# Get Values From SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables that looks like this:

FlightLeg

```
+------+-----+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| FLNO | Seq | FromA | ToA  | DeptTime            | ArrTime             | Plane |
+------+-----+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| 1000 |   1 | DFW   | LOG  | 2020-01-01 01:10:20 | 2020-01-01 01:13:40 |     7 |
| 1010 |   1 | LAX   | ORD  | 2020-01-01 01:13:10 | 2020-01-01 01:16:20 |     3 |
| 1020 |   1 | LOG   | JFK  | 2020-01-01 01:05:40 | 2020-01-01 01:06:20 |     9 |
| 1030 |   1 | LAX   | INT  | 2020-01-01 01:11:20 | 2020-01-01 01:16:10 |     6 |
| 1040 |   1 | LAX   | LGA  | 2020-02-01 01:15:30 | 2020-01-01 01:21:00 |     1 |
| 1010 |   2 | ORD   | JFK  | 2020-01-01 01:17:10 | 2020-01-01 01:20:20 |     3 |
| 1020 |   2 | JFK   | DFW  | 2020-01-01 01:07:20 | 2020-01-01 01:10:20 |     9 |
| 1030 |   2 | INT   | DFW  | 2020-01-01 01:17:20 | 2020-01-01 01:18:00 |     6 |
| 1020 |   3 | DFW   | INT  | 2020-01-01 01:11:10 | 2020-01-01 01:11:40 |     7 |
| 1020 |   4 | INT   | LAX  | 2020-01-01 01:12:20 | 2020-01-01 01:15:10 |     7 |
+------+-----+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

And this:

Flight

```
+------+--------+---------+
| FLNO | Meal   | Smoking |
+------+--------+---------+
| 1000 | Bistro | Y       |
| 1010 | Meal   | N       |
| 1020 | Meal   | Y       |
| 1030 | Snack  | N       |
| 1040 | Meal   | N       |
+------+--------+---------+
```

I'm trying to write a query where for every flight that has more than two legs, retrieve the flight number (FLNO), first departure city (FromA), and the final arrival city of the flight. Flight sequences can start at an arbitray integer and can be separated by an arbitrary integer offset.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FlightLeg.FLNO, (
SELECT FlightLeg.FromA
FROM FlightLeg
INNER JOIN Flight
ON FlightLeg.FLNO=Flight.FLNO
GROUP BY FlightLeg.FLNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2),
(
SELECT FlightLeg.ToA
FROM FlightLeg
INNER JOIN Flight
ON FlightLeg.FLNO=Flight.FLNO
GROUP BY FlightLeg.FLNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)

FROM FlightLeg
INNER JOIN Flight
ON FlightLeg.FLNO=Flight.FLNO
GROUP BY FlightLeg.FLNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

All I can get it to output is the FLNO, FromA, ToA of the first sequence of the correct flight.

Expected output:

```
+------+-------+------+
| FLNO | FromA | ToA  |
+------+-------+------+
| 1020 | LOG   | LAX  |
+------+-------+------+
```

I think I'm really close, but I'm not sure how to account for finding the FromA, for the smallest sequence and the ToA for the largest sequence.

Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your expected output ? Why output should be `1020 LOG LAX` ?

Comment: Also, while it is great how you included your tables, they are not labelled with their names, and the second table seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @CoderofCode Expected output added.

Comment: @Turophile Table labels have been added. And the second one kind of it irrelevant. But I think it makes it easier when you're searching for matching FLNO in both tables first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a self-join and a derived table like this:

```
select flight_start.flno, flight_start.froma, flight_end.toa 
from flightleg flight_start
join flightleg flight_end on flight_start.flno = flight_end.flno
join (
  select 
    flno,
    min(seq) origin,
    max(seq) destination
  from flightleg
  group by flno
  having count(*) > 2
) min_max_seq
 on flight_start.flno = min_max_seq.flno 
and flight_start.seq  = min_max_seq.origin
and flight_end.seq    = min_max_seq.destination
```

The query used as the derived table determines the lowest and highest seq number for each flight, and the first join uses the lower sequence number to retrieve the origin airport while the second join uses the higher sequence number to retrieve the destination airport. The number of legs is determined in the `having` clause in the derived table.

On a side note: if the sequence numbers aren't a good determinant for the order then you could use the dates instead to determine which the order or legs.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28e05/1)

Comment: `Flight sequences can start at an arbitray integer and can be separated by an arbitrary integer offset.` Not sure if using a max and min on sequence will work in this case (not sure if its reliable at all), but I like the query

Comment: @JohnRuddell I noticed that too, but I assumed that the sequence grows upward.

Comment: yea I would hope thats how anyone stores data... but ive seen weird things sometimes lol +1 from me though

Answer (score 2):

```
select  x.flno, 
        Max( if( y.DeptTime = x.starter, y.FromA, null )) FirstLegFrom,
        Max( if( y.DeptTime = x.starter, y.DeptTime, null )) FirstLegStart,
        Max( if( y.DeptTime = x.ender, y.ToA, null )) LastLegFrom,
        Max( if( y.DeptTime = x.ender, y.ArrTime, null )) LastLegArrival
from(
    select  flno, min(depttime) as starter, max(depttime) as ender
    from    flightleg
    group by flno
    having count(*) > 2
) x
join   flightleg y
  on   x.flno = y.flno
  and  (x.starter = y.depttime
    or  x.ender = y.depttime)
group by x.flno;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79640/1/0
(with modification proposed by TommCatt for efficiency)

This does not rely on `seq` being in ascending order for each flight.

Comment: Much better to use the dates rather than the, as described, "arbitrary" seq values. Always select the most meaningful data. However, if I may suggest a slight variation to perform only one join rather than two: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79640/16

Comment: Agreed re: doing away with one of the joins